# No wireless internet connection in Debian

Tags: debian, internet

I have installed debian 8 jessie via usb. I have no internet connection on the laptop, how can i fix this? The internet is working fine, i have internet on another ubuntu machine.
Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LM Gigabit 
Network Connection [8086:10ea] (rev 06)
Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:2153]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:4239] (rev 35)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1311]
ff:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers [8086:2c62] (rev 02)
```

Comment: What wireless device are you using?

Comment: the result of `ifconfig -a` shows a `eth0` and a `lo` (with descriptions). Is that what you mean?

Comment: please edit and add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Comment: @AmirTeymuri Please , If you solve the first problem ( you can connect Wired)you can edit by adding the wifi problem, My answer will be wrong after your second edit.

Answer (score 0):

Download  the intel driver `e1000e` from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/15817)

unzip the archive

```
tar zxf e1000e-3.3.3.tar
```

Change to the driver `src` directory:

```
cd e1000e-3.3.3/src/
```

Install

```
make install
```

unload and load driver:

```
rmmod e1000e
modprobe e1000e
```

update `initramfs`

```
update-initramfs -u
```

**Edit**

Reboot

Connect to the internet

Edit your `sources.list`

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add the following line:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

install iwlwifi driver

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi ; modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: He is asking about wireless, not wired interface for which the module seems to load correctly.

Comment: @piernov Before editing the question , he is not able to connect through Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Centrino chipsets usually need the iwlwifi driver.  Make sure it is loaded.

```
$ sudo lsmod | grep iwlwifi
```

If it is not loaded, try loading it

```
$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

If that fixes it, then you should see the wireless APs being listed in network manager.